# Почему BufferedOutputStream не выводит данные?

Tags: java

Задача создать свой класс Stream, который бы выводил данные из системного входного потока в выходной поток и в файл, используя BufferedStream. Данные из BufferedOutputStream не выводятся. Как вывести данные из BufferedStream? При записи в файл правильно ли использовать BufferedStream, чтобы не обращаться к файлу много раз или java делает это автоматически?

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DoubleEndedStream {
    InputStream theInput;
    OutputStream theOutput;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {               
    DoubleEndedStream sr = new DoubleEndedStream(System.in, System.out);
    sr.doublingTheStream();
}

public DoubleEndedStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    theInput = in;
    theOutput = out;    
}

public void doublingTheStream() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException  {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\log.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bout1 = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedOutputStream bout2 = new BufferedOutputStream(theOutput);
        try {
            while (true) {
                int datum = theInput.read();
                if (datum == -1) break;
                bout1.write(datum);
                bout2.write(datum);
            }
            bout1.flush();
            bout2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't read from System.in!");
        }

        bout1.close();
        bout2.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find log.txt");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while (true) {
>                 int datum = theInput.read();
>                 if (datum == -1) break;

datum не принимает значение -1, так как не достигнут конец потока System.in. для нормальной работы, необходимо другое условие проверки(например, нажатие спецсимвола)

Comment: А как можно без использования спец. символа не потерять данные, которые не вывелись из буфера?